# Oracle subquery's SELECT MAX() on large dataset is very slow

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery

The following SQL :

```
SELECT *
FROM   Transaction_Auth_Series t
WHERE  t.Auth_ID = 
(
  SELECT MAX(p.Session_ID)
  FROM   Clone_Db_Derective p
  WHERE  p.Date = trunc(sysdate)
  AND    p.Regularity = 'THEME'
);
```

is very slow when the referred tables contain about 300 million rows. But, it's just a matter of few seconds when the SQL is written in two cursors, i.e.

```
  CURSOR GetMaxValue IS
    SELECT MAX(p.Session_ID)
      FROM   Clone_Db_Derective p
      WHERE  p.Date = trunc(sysdate)
      AND    p.Regularity = 'THEME'

  CURSOR GetAllItems(temp VARCHAR2) IS
    SELECT *
    FROM   Transaction_Auth_Series t
    WHERE  t.Auth_ID = temp;
```

and

```
........
  FOR item in GETMAX LOOP
    FOR itemx in GETITEMS(item.aaa) LOOP.......
```

Joins won't work as the tables are not related. How can we optimize the above main SQL please?

Comment: Possibly the execution plan is not optimal. For example, perhaps the optimiser has internally transformed it to perform the join first, based on the table statistics. If so, you may be able to fix the stats or rearrange or hint the query.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your suggestion @WilliamRobertson?

Comment: If the execution plan is bad for a simple query like this, it usually means the stats are wrong. So, a SQL tuning exercise involves checking the plan and reviewing the stats. How do they look?

Comment: Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
       1205  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
   87542484  consistent gets
    3225786  physical reads
      10984  redo size
     833979  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
       1862  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
        138  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
         23  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
       2047  rows processed

Comment: That's lovely but it isn't the execution plan or the table statistics.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM Transaction_Auth_Series t
WHERE t.Auth_ID = (SELECT MAX(p.Session_ID)
                   FROM Clone_Db_Derective p
                   WHERE p.Date = trunc(sysdate) AND p.Regularity = 'THEME'
                  );
```

I would recommend indexes on `Clone_Db_Derective(Regularity, Date, Session_ID)` and `Transaction_Auth_Series(Auth_Id)`.

The optimization for this query (assuming the tables are not views) seems pretty simple.  I am surprised that the cursor version is so much faster.

Comment: Yes, the cursor version retrieves the required data within seconds. However, the Transaction_Auth_Series is a view, and Clone_Db_Derective is indexed.

Comment: @MaDi . . . The view may be confusing the optimizer.  You might try moving the subquery to the `FROM` clause and using a `JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the joins doesn't help it seems. These are not related so it won't help for sure, isn't it?

Comment: @MaDi - "join" in this context would be a Cartesian join. The second "table" (inline view) is the result of the MAX computation - it is a scalar "table" (with only one row and one column). This will force Oracle to compute the MAX first, and not to try other weird things. Worth a try for sure!

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH max_session
     AS (SELECT MAX (p.Session_ID) id
           FROM Clone_Db_Derective p
          WHERE p.Date = TRUNC (SYSDATE) AND p.Regularity = 'THEME')
SELECT *
  FROM Transaction_Auth_Series t
 WHERE t.Auth_ID = (SELECT id FROM max_session)
```

A WITH clause is most valuable when the result of the WITH query is required more than one time in the body of the main query such as where one averaged value needs to be compared against two or three times. The point is to minimize the number of accesses to a table joined multiple times into a single query.

Comment: I have tried the WITH but with no success. It still takes much time (around 160 seconds whereas the CURSOR option takes only about two seconds)

Comment: The point, though, is that the subquery is used ONLY ONE TIME in the OP's overall query. In this case I don't see how a WITH clause would change anything, since the optimizer will transform your query (in this Answer) into the OP's original query.